# Обрезка строки в java

Tags: java, строки

Приветствую. Есть строка - `"добрый день[флажек]дорогие друзъя."`
Как можно разделить строку на две, до и после `"[флажек]"`?

Comment: задайте пожалуйста новый вопрос, a не редактируйте этот (уже закрытый) вопрос-дубликат.

Comment: ...т. к. замена одного вопроса (особенно с ответами, особенно высоко оценёнными) совершенно другим вопросом классифицируется как вандализм.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Метод `split()` в Java разделяет данную строку вокруг данного регулярного выражения

Синтаксис этого метода: `public String[] split(String regex, int limit)` или `public String[] split(String regex)`, где

- regex - разграничение регулярного выражения;
- limit - порог, результатом которого означает, как много строк, должно быть возвращено.

split() возвращает массив строк.

---

```
String str = "добрый день[флажек]дорогие друзъя";
String[] strArr = str.split("\\[флажек\\]");
System.out.print("часть до разделителя: " + strArr[0] + ", часть после разделителя:" + strArr[1]);
```

Comment: Экранировать `]` тут необязательно, сойдёт и `"\\[флажек]"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а из всей геометрии ненавижу симметрии...:)